# what does num_epochs means in eval_input_config TF2 object detection API v2

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0, object-detection, object-detection-api, tensorflow-model-garden

what does `num_epochs` means in the `eval_input_config` in the pipeline.config
I noticed that when I change the value of this field to more than 1 I'm having these **warning**  logs when trying to **train an object detection model** using **Tensorflow Object Detection API 2**

`[04/14 22:39:04] tensorflow WARNING: Ignoring detection with image id 163697061 since it was previously added`

```
eval_input_reader: {
  label_map_path: "PATH_TO_BE_CONFIGURED/label_map.txt"
  shuffle: false
  num_epochs: 1
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "PATH_TO_BE_CONFIGURED/val2017-?????-of-00032.tfrecord"
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, one epoch is a single pass through your entire training set,and you would need  to run multiple epochs until the model converges while **training**.
However, since in this case, it's inside the `eval_input_reader`, it should be `1` because for validation, you need to go through the test/validation set only once. It doesn't make sense to go over the validation set multiple times as the weights don't get updated/no backpropagation happens

Comment: In my code, I'm running the evaluation in parallel to the training loop so whenever there is a new checkpoint created the evaluation loop will evaluate and pass through the whole validation set right? so there is no need to change the number of epochs to more than one because at every evaluation process it is evaluating all the validation set?

Comment: Yes @user8912375 there's no need to make it greater than one